# Are there any criteria for a presheaf which is an etale sheaf to be a sheaf in the fppf topology? 

Tags: sheaf-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

I am happy to hear answers to variants too. For instance,  my situation I actually have a sheaf in the smooth topology.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're looking for a different answer, but I may as well throw this out there. If an etale sheaf has a representable etale cover by a scheme (i.e. if it is an algebraic space), then it is an fppf sheaf.